# Animating back and forth not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a container have a color animating back and forth from green to yellow. I tried the following, but it animates from green to yellow and not from yellow to green..

```
class MyAnimmmmmState extends State<MyAnimmmm> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animCtrl;
  Animation<Color> colorAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animCtrl = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1))..repeat(reverse: true);
    colorAnimation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.yellow).animate(animCtrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animCtrl,
          builder: (_, __) => Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: StadiumBorder(), color: colorAnimation.value),
              child: Center(child: Text('yooosters', style: TextStyle())))),
}
```

How can I get it to animate back and forth?

Comment: Your code is working fine: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b?

Comment: @MidhunMP The link u sent has the default counter app.

Comment: @MidhunMP It's working fine, but it's not animating from yellow to green. Only from green to yellow. It jumps from yellow to green without animating

Comment: I tried your code in dartpad it's working fine without any issue. It's not jumping back, if you set `repeat(reverse: false)` then you can see the jumping issue.